# XMLTask convert &apos; to '

Tags: xml, encoding, xmltask

When i run xmltask it's convert tags like **`&apos;`** to **`'`** .
Example: 
From:
`<Value>&apos;operation&apos;</Value>`
To:
`<Value>'operation'</Value>`

**How can I avoid this auto converting?**
I want that **`&apos;`** to stay as it is.

Comment: Why? They two representations are equivalent (and `'` uses fewer bytes and is much easier to read)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `expandEntityReferences` attribute to `false`:

```
<xmltask source="..." dest="..." expandEntityReferences="false"/>
```

Comment: Sorry, i did it but it's not help.

Comment: May i need to do some changes in : FormattedDataWriter or Outputter or XMLWriter files ? to prvent this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to keep your `&apos`, you can try this :

write `&amp;apos;` instead of `&apos;`

it will be processed like this :

`&amp;apos;` => `&apos;`
(instead of `&apos;` => `'`)

Which means you have to replace every `&` with `&amp;`...

There must be a smarter solution

Apolo

Comment: I have xml :
<Value>&apos;operation&apos;</Value>
When i run xmltask on it and for example change operation to operation2, in result i have :
Result: <Value>'operation2'</Value> Expected: <Value>&apos;operation2&apos;</Value>

Comment: you can't change your xml to `<Value>&amp;apos;operation&amp;apos;</Value>` ?

Comment: I converted, but final result : 
<Value>&amp;apos;operation&amp;apos;</Value>
It's not &amp;apos; => &apos;
It's &amp;apos; => &amp;apos;

Comment: did you changed the expandEntityReferences like it is suggested in the other answer ? (if you did, it should not convert &amp; to & ...)

Comment: What do you mean changes in expandEntityReferences ?

Comment: He told you to write `<xmltask source="..." dest="..." expandEntityReferences="false"/>`, and you told him it has changed nothing. Have you left `expandEntityReferences="false"` ?

Comment: >My code is :  <br/>
`<xmltask source="Z:\secure.xml" dest="Z:\secure.xml" expandEntityReferences="false">
<regexp path="/Table/Value/text()" pattern="&apos;" replace="&amp;apos;"/>
</xmltask>`
>Final Result:`<Value>&amp;apos;secure&amp;apos;</Value>`
>**Expected**:`<Value>&apos;secure&apos;</Value>`

Comment: try with expandEntityReferences="true"

Comment: Same issue, also added an encoding="UTF-8" to <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Comment: try `pattern="&" replace="&amp;"`